# Open multiple subfolders within a loop

Tags: matlab

I have a folder named "Photos" that is a subfolder of the current directory. Inside that folder, there are four subfolders with names "Order1", "Order2", 
"Order3", "Order4". I am trying to open these subfolders using a loop.

The following code is not working.

```
for i=1:4
    current_path=pwd;
    cd(current_path');
    cd('Photos\Order%d',i);
end
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in cd(current_path');

Comment: Thanks, Yes. I removed it. the problem with cd('Photos\Order%d',i).It is still not working

Comment: Read the error message, it tells you what the problem is.

Comment: I'm no expert but it seems a bit like python what you are trying to do. Maybe something like cd('Photos\Order' + num2str(i)) will work for you.

Comment: @Uzzee: The `'` is nonsense but causes no problem.

Comment: Thanks. it says, Too many input arguments. for cd('Photos\Order%d',i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot issues going on here at the same time.

1. The primary issue is that you are changing directories each time through the loop but you're *also* getting the value of the current directory (`pwd`) *each* time. The directory doesn't automatically reset to where you were when it goes back to the top of the loop. I *think* you expect `current_path` to be the folder you *started* in and be the same for all iterations.
2. You need to use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) or something similar to create your "OrderN" folder names. [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) doesn't know what to do with the [format specifier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) you're trying to use.
3. You should *always* use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) when concatenating file paths. Period.
4. You should use *absolute* paths when possible to remove the dependence upon the current directory.
5. Do you *really* need to change the working directory? If you're trying to load files within these folders, please consider using *absolute file paths* to the files themselves rather than changing folders.
6. If you *are* going to do this this way, please be sure to reset the path back to where it was at the end of the loop. There is nothing worse than running code and ending up in a directory that is different than where you were when you called it.

To actually make your code work, we could do something like this. But given all of my points above (specifically, 4-5), I would strongly consider a different approach.

```
startpath = pwd;

for k = 1:4
    folder = fullfile(startpath, 'Photos', sprintf('Order%d', k));
    cd(folder)
end

% Set the current directory to what it was before we started
cd(startpath)
```

Comment: @user6052232 Please take the time to read and *understand* all the points that I have made above. Don't simply copy/paste code.

Comment: @Suever Actually, I am writing a program and the results are photos in four folders after that I will change this photos to video. The photos in each folder will create a separate movie. I will get four movies. That’s why I want to use loop in order to read that photos

Comment: @user6052232 It's fine to do that, just try to avoid using `cd`. You can create the absolute path to the files instead. `fullfile(startpath, 'Photos', sprintf('Order%d', k), 'imagefile1.png')` etc.